# jQuery if condition not working properly based on conditions

Tags: jquery

Why `button` is not disabled when the value for each box is same.

I have 4 textboxs, 2 textboxs for compare Department Name and 2 textboxs for compare Department Active.

```js
$("#departmentIDInput, #departmentNameInput, #departmentActive").bind("keyup change", function() {
  var departmentIDInput = $("#departmentIDInput").val();
  var departmentNameInput = $("#departmentNameInput").val();
  var departmentNameInputCurrent = $("#departmentNameInputCurrent").val();
  var departmentActive = $("#departmentActive").val();
  var departmentActiveVal = $("#departmentActiveVal").val();
  var departmentActiveValCurrent = $("#departmentActiveValCurrent").val();

  if (departmentNameInput != departmentNameInputCurrent) {
    $("#btnUpdate").attr('disabled', false).removeClass('btn_inact').addClass('btn_act');
  } else {
    $("#btnUpdate").attr('disabled', true).removeClass('btn_act').addClass('btn_inact');
  }

  if (departmentActiveVal == departmentActiveValCurrent) {
    $("#btnUpdate").attr('disabled', false).removeClass('btn_inact').addClass('btn_act');
  } else {
    $("#btnUpdate").attr('disabled', true).removeClass('btn_act').addClass('btn_inact');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="departmentNameInput" name="departmentNameInput" maxlength="30" value="Production"/>
<input type="text" id="departmentNameInputCurrent" name="departmentNameInputCurrent" maxlength="30" value="Production"/>

<input type="text" name="departmentActiveVal" class="departmentActiveVal" id="departmentActiveVal" value="Y"/>
<input type="text" name="departmentActiveValCurrent" class="departmentActiveValCurrent" id="departmentActiveValCurrent" value="Y"/>

<input type="checkbox" class="departmentActive" id="departmentActive" />

<input type="button" class="button turquoise" id="btnUpdate" value="Update" disabled/>
```

1. If checkbox click or un-click, the button working good
2. When type something to "departmentNameInput", example: Productions (On departmentNameInputCurrent is: Production), the button is working good, means disabled. But when I try to delete the text back again same with "departmentNameInputCurrent", the button is not disable.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: There is no button in your HTML sample. Also use `prop()` not `attr()` to set the disabled state of the button

Answer (score 0):

The button is not disabled when the value for each box is same because of your second if-condition.

```
 if (departmentActiveVal == departmentActiveValCurrent) {
    $("#btnUpdate").attr('disabled', false).removeClass('btn_inact').addClass('btn_act');
  }
```

This evaluates to true and the button will be enabled

Comment: You just have to use a simple and -  if (departmentNameInput != departmentNameInputCurrent && departmentActiveVal == departmentActiveValCurrent) { ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try simplifying your functions within ternary operation such as:

```js
$("#departmentIDInput, #departmentNameInput, #departmentActive").bind("keyup change", function() {
  var departmentIDInput = $("#departmentIDInput").val();
  var departmentNameInput = $("#departmentNameInput").val();
  var departmentNameInputCurrent = $("#departmentNameInputCurrent").val();
  var departmentActive = $("#departmentActive").val();
  var departmentActiveVal = $("#departmentActiveVal").val();
  var departmentActiveValCurrent = $("#departmentActiveValCurrent").val();
  var isNameEqual = departmentNameInput === departmentNameInputCurrent;
  var isActiveValueEqual = departmentActiveVal === departmentActiveValCurrent;
  var isDisabled = isNameEqual && isActiveValueEqual;

  $("#btnUpdate").prop('disabled', isDisabled).removeClass('btn_inact').addClass('btn_act');
});
```